# Как правильно создать регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Добрый день.

Помогите набросать регулярку:

Есть текст (html код). В нем присутсвуют элементы **{@SomeText@}**. Встречаются как подряд идущие **{@SomeText@}****{@SomeText@}**, так и через пробел\строку, в общем, встречаются в разных видах.
Необходимо дать в preg_match_all регулярку, чтобы получить массивы этих самых элементов.
Сооветственно, SomeText меняется, но не может содержать пробелы или @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=@)\w+(?=@)
```

- вот так попробуйте.

Comment: про пробелы  забыли 

    (?<=@)[\S\s]+?(?=@)

Comment: Сооветственно SomeText меняется, но не может содержать пробелы или @.

Comment: Доходит до первого элемента и всё (
Вот пример текста
<li>{@element1@} {@ele ment@}<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o">{@element2@}{@ele ment@}</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Страницы</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Блоки</a></li>

Comment: Вот:

    <?php
    $text = '<li>{@element1@} {@ele ment@}<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Главная</a></li> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-o">{@element2@}{@ele ment@}</i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Страницы</a></li> <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cube"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Блоки</a></li>';

    preg_match_all('/(?<=@)\w+(?=@)/',$text,$arr);

    print_r($arr);
    ?>

Выводит 

Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => element1 [1] => element2 ) )

ele ment, ес-но, не выводит, так как 

  >но не может содержать пробелы

Comment: Как раз сам доработал ваш регексп. Спасибо, работает!

Comment: @dolphin4ik, у вас идет element1, ele ment, element2, ele ment. Как вы хотите это обработать? 
Приведите, пожалуйста, пример исходного, завершенного(!) текста для обработки и того, что вы хотите получить в итоге. Запостить можно, например, на pastebin.com и скинуть сюда ссылку.